# Javascript based data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing a javascript client side API which connects to REST and retrieves a the results of an SQL query in the form of a xml/json.
I would like to load this information into a structure that would allow me to manipulate the data easily from the javascript bit, i.e. sort the information based on a column name, lookups, etc... 
I noticed many solutions for the above that are based on an HTML table being generated/manipulated, however I don't want to draw the table in anyway, just be able to query it locally.

It needs to serve as a structured local data store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like how frameworks and NoSQL databases do it - document-based databases. It's basically using arrays and object literals as a storage medium in your page. when you need to persist it, use `JSON.stringify()` to turn it into a string and store in the localstorage and parse it later with `JSON.parse()`

as for manipulations like sorting and ordering the data, you can craft your own, or use other frameworks which already have functions to do this work.

i would suggest looking into [BackboneJS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and how it handles it's model and collection. also, you might want to take a look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) also, and it's NoSQL, JSON-format database.

Comment: Thanks for this, this solves one part of the equation, how to persist the object once I have it constructed. However, I was hoping that with regards to the implementation of the above arrays and object literals, there is an available solution that a smarter person as wrote :)

Comment: @mr.kav have a look at MongoDB for the storage structure and BackboneJS for the client-side RESTful data store.

Comment: thanks for the info, I had a look and they both seem like a very robust solution. However in my case, I already have a complex environment here that caters all of my needs. Just need a "simple" data structure that doesn't require its own dedicated setup like Mongo, and does not use its own REST like Backbone. I did get to underscore.js from backbone.js, so I'll give that a try.